# HP DL180g6 requires operator intervention to boot on one power supply

Tags: hp-proliant, boot, power-supply-unit

Summary: Used DL180g6, with redundant power supplies, that just came in will not boot unless either both supplies are powered or the operator presses F1 on the keyboard.  If 2nd supply comes up after that message is on screen, boot will NOT resume.

A while back I set up an HP DL180g6 for a client.  He likes it, so when some used DL180g6 units came up used for cheap, he wanted to buy and set up a backup server.  I got the used DL180, and threw it in a rack to set it up before shipping it out.  I was in a hurry, so I only ran one power cord.  Found out that this computer will only boot unattended if BOTH power supplies are on.

If only one power supply is on, boot will proceed through RAID controller screen, but then, instead of proceeding to the "press F10 for BIOS" screen, it goes back to the first screen with the message:
624-Power Supply Failure or Power Supply Unplugged
Press F1 to continue.

These servers are set to power on whenever power is restored.  The original unit will boot as long as either supply is powered.  This one stops forever waiting for someone to press F1.  Even worse, if power to the second supply is restored, it STAYS STUCK.

Is this a BIOS version issue, or did I get some oddball version of the DL180g6 or what?  These units are installed over 1700 miles (over 2500km) away in a 3rd world country, where power failures happen EVERY DAY.  The computers are protected by UPS and generator (all automatic), but things do malfunction when they are cycled more than once a day.  The two power supplies are fed from totally different power chains, and so those chains may not come back at the same time.  The fact that the boot will not continue even when both supplies are running is particularly galling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that the previous owners changed the POST (Power On Self Test) settings. Reboot the server and enter the BIOS, on the first page scroll down to the bottom and you should see an option like "POST F1 Prompt", make sure it says "Delayed". This won't stop the prompt but will stop it from stopping completely. The menu options might need to be tracked down as they might shift depending on BIOS version.

Comment: You nailed it.  At the very bottom of the first screen the setting is called:

POST F1 prompt

with choices: Enabled/Disabled/Delayed

This was set to "Enabled".  Changing it to "Delayed" stops at the same point in the boot, so the error can be seen, but has a 15 second countdown.  When it gets to 0, the boot process continues.

I marked your response as the answer, but don't have enough reputation to upvote it.  Hope it helps someone else.